# Thermal power station powered by temperature difference between high and low altitude air

Tags: electricity, power, air, thermoelectricity

Would it be feasible to build a system where warm air from sea level is pumped to the top of a mountain to power a thermal power station?

With a [lapse rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapse_rate) of ~ 1°C / 100 m there should be plenty of thermal energy available.

Comment: A good deal of that lapse rate is due to air expansion, so even under the best of conditions (adiabatic), the warm surface air would be substantially cooled by the time it got to the mountain top.

Comment: But if it's contained in a pipe, it wouldn't expand, would it? This, however, would mean that the air is basically compressed (in comparison to the surrounding air) while being pumped to the mountain top, which would further decrease efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is efficiency ($\eta$), that is the amount of heat energy $Q$ that you can convert into mechanical work $W$:
$$\eta=\frac{W}{Q}$$

For most heat machines:
$$\eta\approx 1-\frac{T_C}{T_H}$$

where $T_C$ is the temperature of the cold sink (in $\mathrm{K}$) and $T_H$ is the temperature of the hot sink (in $\mathrm{K}$)

With $T_C\approx T_H$ (in your proposed case), then:

$$\eta\approx 0$$

Comment: Why do you think that $T_C\approx T_H$? 

Comment: @adius Because the drop in temperature (for a realistically high mountain) is really quite small. From your own link the lapse is about $9.8\,\mathrm{C/km}$, so for Everest about $80\,\mathrm{C}$ Plug that into the formula for $\eta$ and find how small it is!

Answer (score 0):

The relationship of altitude to temperature of air is dominated by the adiabatic expansion effect; air expands at
the lower pressure of a mountaintop, and cools in that process.  Conversely, air flowing down from a mountain
will rise in temperature, without heat input, only because of the rise in pressure.   The process is called adiabatic
because heat is not moved to or from the gas, only the temperature rises or falls.   The hypothetical heat engine
DOES exchange heat with the working fluid, so must be in contact with the whole mass of that fluid.

If you want to move constant-temperature material from low to high altitudes, and  make a heat engine from this, pumping an
incompressible liquid (water) would work better.  Being incompressible, there is no adiabatic cooling.   The downward water return can run turbines to compensate for the pump energy required for  upward delivery.

Better still, is to use geology: prevailing winds push
air west-to-east, so the western shore of a continent
has moist ocean air coming to  higher altitude where there are north-south mountain ranges.  Some of
the high-altitude air mass becomes snow, falls to the
mountain heights, and through the year will melt and provide rivers whose flow can run turbines. This kind of heat engine is in contact with a LOT of working fluid, at little cost to the turbine operator.